# Attempt to de-reference a null object while assigning values to wrapper class

Tags: apex

I am trying to edit a record. So while editing i am querying all the fields in the constructor.

I am using a  wrapper class to which i am assigning assigning values from query. At that time i am getting

Attempt to de-reference a null object.

Below is the constructor  and wrapper class -

```
 wrappers=new List<AccountWrapper>();

   AccountWrapper firstAccountWrapper = new AccountWrapper(0);
 firstAccountWrapper.acc.Start_Date__c = datev.Start_Date__c;
 firstAccountWrapper.acc.End_Date__c= datev.End_Date__c;
  wrappers.add(firstAccountWrapper);

  if(wrappers.size() ==0){
  for (Integer idx=0; idx<1; idx++)
  {
   wrappers.add(new AccountWrapper(nextIdent++));
  }
  }
 }
```

Comment: wrappers[0].acc.Start_Date__c =datev.Start_Date__c;  in the constuctor..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you're calling the `wrappers` variable is when you're trying to take the first element from it.  You haven't yet initialised it.

It is therefore considered a `null` object, and you're trying to de-reference it.

You'll need to instantiate the `wrappers` variable before you can use it.

i.e.

```
//  Assuming you've declared the wrappers variable 
wrappers = new List<AccountWrapper>(); 
AccountWrapper firstAccountWrapper = new AccountWrapper(0);
firstAccountWrapper.acc.Start_Date__c = datev.Start_Date__c;
wrappers.add(firstAccountWrapper);
```

Although I don't know what you're doing with the index, so you may want to handle the index number differently.

Comment: r u telling to use wrappers=new List<AccountWrapper>(); above the line..

Comment: @learnjqueery pretty much, plus you'll need to initialise the AccountWrapper that is your first element

Comment: Hi Nick.. how to initialise the AccountWrapper.. Can u give me some clue..

Comment: @learnjqueery see updated answer

Comment: Hi Nick,, Thanks i am not getting that error now .. I am able to populate the values. But the problem is happening is that .. Actually thriugh the wrapper class i am dynamically creating date field..After using ur code i am getting the values plus one blank row of date field..

Comment: I have updated my code.

Comment: I think i got it .. I kept a check of wrappers variable size..

Comment: @learnjqueery Great to hear it's working. If there are other questions, I'd suggest starting a new question.  This site is about Q&A, so if this answer works for you, mark it as the correct one.  If there are further errors/issues, start a new question.  Hope it all works for you!